# get object from another class

Tags: python, composition

I'm trying to get an object from class B in class A because the class A is composed by object of class B:

```
ObjectClassB = [ObjectCLassA1,ObjectClassA2,ObjectClassA3]
```

with ObjectClassA are sublists of Class B.

With this code I'm trying to add an element to one object of Class B to get this result:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [6,7,8]]
```

```
class B: 
    def __init__(self,X,Y,Z):
        self.X=X
        self.Y=Y
        self.Z=Z
    def Xreturner(self):
        return self.X
    def Yreturner(self):
        return self.Y
    def Zreturner(self):
        return self.Z

class A: # the class A is a composed from many object of B
    def __init__(self):
        self.ls=[]
        self.lst=[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]] # 
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.lst)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__) 

    def add(self,X,Y,Z): # trying to add b object to the list
        b=B(X,Y,Z)
        print(b)
        self.ls.append(b)
        self.lst.append(self.ls)
        print(self.lst)
#### TEST####
objA=A()
objA.add(6,7,8)
```

When I execute this test I get for `print(b)`:

```
>>> <__main__.B instance at 0x1d8ab90>
```

and for `print(self.lst)`:

```
>>> [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [...]]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you sure about this line? self.lst.append(self.lst) looks weird

Comment: ah i should edit this
 self.lst.append(self.ls)

Comment: after the edit i get this >>>[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [<__main__.B instance at 0x1f99b90>]]

Comment: `Xreturner` is a strange name for a function... and not really necessary when you can use `b.X` at any point for any `B` instance

Comment: You are appending an object of type B to the list. What I think you want to do is something like self.ls.append([X, Y, Z])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem there is that you are trying to `print` an object. `print(b)` will print the address of the object in memory since it can't infer what should be printed.

```
class B: 
    def __init__(self,X,Y,Z):
        self.X=X
        self.Y=Y
        self.Z=Z
    def Xreturner(self):
        return self.X
    def Yreturner(self):
        return self.Y
    def Zreturner(self):
        return self.Z
    def listReturner(self):
        return [self.X, self.Y, self.Z] #return a list ready to be added

class A: # the class A is a composed from many object of B
    def __init__(self):
        self.ls=[]
        self.lst=[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]] # 
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.lst)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__) 

    def add(self,X,Y,Z): # trying to add b object to the list
        b=B(X,Y,Z)
        print(b) #Will print the address of b
        print(b.X) #Will print the value of X in b
        self.ls.append(b)

        self.ls.append([b.X, b.Y, b.Z]) ### EDIT: this will add the desired values to the list

        print(self.ls) #Will print the addresses of the objects in the list
        print([a.X for a in self.ls]) #Will print the values of X for each object in the list
        self.lst.append(self.lst) #This line might be wrong
        print(self.lst)
#### TEST####
objA=A()
objA.add(6,7,8)
```

Comment: and how can i get the value of this instance ?

Comment: You can use b.X, b.Y or b.Z. It is an object with variables.

Comment: self.ls.append([b.X, b.Y, b.Z]) will add the desired values to the list

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, your code is (more or less: more below) doing things right, and all you really need to fix is the way `class B` **presents** itself to the world upon print. For that, you can add a `__repr__` method to `class B` which will fix that.

The other issue I see, is with `self.lst.append(self.ls)` which will append to the list `lst` a list-of-list. I think you can skip that, and just run the `self.lst.append(b)` and be done.

Note that still, the first two elements in the `self.lst` of  `class A` are **not** of type `class B`, but I guess that's how you want it to work.

Code here, and also see it in action on: https://eval.in/671341

```
class B: 
    def __init__(self,X,Y,Z):
        self.X=X
        self.Y=Y
        self.Z=Z
    def Xreturner(self):
        return self.X
    def Yreturner(self):
        return self.Y
    def Zreturner(self):
        return self.Z
    def __repr__(self):
        return str([self.X, self.Y, self.Z])


class A: # the class A is a composed from many object of B
    def __init__(self):
        self.ls=[]
        self.lst=[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]] # 
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.lst)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__) 

    def add(self,X,Y,Z): # trying to add b object to the list
        b=B(X,Y,Z)
        print(b)
        # self.ls.append(b)         # b will be represented as list
        # self.lst.append(self.ls)  # double append: let's not do that
        self.lst.append(b)          # simply append the object
        print(self.lst)
#### TEST####
objA=A()
objA.add(6,7,8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal example of what you want.

Implement `__repr__` on `B`

```
class B: 
    def __init__(self,X,Y,Z):
        self.X=X
        self.Y=Y
        self.Z=Z

    def __repr__(self):
        return str([self.X, self.Y, self.Z])

b1 = B(1, 2, 3)
b2 = B(3, 4, 5)

print(b1)  # [1, 2, 3]

b_list = [b1, b2]

print(b_list) # [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
```